# UV wrapping brushed steel hard-surface models

Tags: texturing, uv

So I have one today I hope really can be found by others and learned from! I am really trying to create some high quality models and I think the area I am having the hardest time with is proper UV wrapping. I am working with a brushed steel material from Poliigon.com and I want the angle of the brushed lines in specific directions.

First, here is the model and texture:
[image]

Now, despite my best efforts, and hours on YouTube this model is still loaded with imperfections. Here are just a few examples:
[image]

Lastly here is the desired flow I am wanting for my brushed lines:
[image]

So, I am really just curious if anyone has any pointers, or ideas as to how I can get really tight clean UV wraps or even point me in the direction of a paid course, etc. I have learned a lot about seams, marking sharp, and even the general process of UV wrapping and it's interface within Blender. However, wrapping these lines in a seamless and flawless manner, that point in the desired direction, is beyond me at the moment and ANY help would be incredibly appreciated!

I hope this also can help others who are struggling with intermediate level UV stuff.

Let me know if someone wants the .blend

THANK YOU ALL !!!

[image]

Comment: consider this: you first brush the metal then you bend it into shape. your uv maps should look like the piece of metal sheet before bending.

Comment: well the texture I have is just horizontal lines, and since I want these lines to go in several different directions I am not sure what you mean by wrap

Comment: I request for the blend file

Comment: I posted the file for you Shantanu. Thank you very much for your interest! I stripped down the file and even the textures a little bit but feel free to use another brushed style texture if you have one similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]
Some of the texture files were missing so I used the waves texture instead.

[image]

Comment: wow.... Can you provide a brief explanation ( or a detailed one if you feel generous ) of the magic that you laid down on this file ??

Really impressed!!

Would you use some sort of a blend in your shader tab to make sure there is no visible seam ?

Comment: @CameronT0101 to blend the seams you can use a similar approach: https://youtu.be/Ebx2qbBlvh0?t=563

Comment: Ok funnily enough I was actually watching this video for this problem, so I will certainly watch it once more! Ok my last question would just be:

Was there any technique or tool that you used that I should know about in order to execute this process in the future?

I will also download the blend and TRY to learn as much as I can!

Thank you again, and I will give you the answer mark :)